# After turning my monitor off and on, it will display only a white screen

Tags: graphics-card, display

About a month after installing a new graphics card, I started encountering a rather frustrating problem. Namely, if I turn my monitor off for any significant length of time, then turn it back on, it displays only a white screen.

Previously, restarting could fix the problem. However, after leaving the computer off last night, the problem persists.

An internet search turned up [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/forum/questions/101-214136) site; however, the monitor cable is not loose. As for the insides of the monitor - Well, I could poke around, but I risk making it worse if it's not the monitor. Any such instructions should be clear, detailed and include pictures.

Further updates as events warrant.

Comment: Connected a different monitor; worked fine.

Comment: You've pretty much isolated the problem to the monitor (and perhaps the cable, if you swapped that too). *Unless* the swapped in monitor connects to your graphics card differently (analog vs. digital, f/ex), in which case it could be an early death of that part of the new graphics card.  Have you tried checking its setup options, or even whether the setup page can display?  If none of that pans out, I'd say monitor died.

Comment: The monitor I tried is an older LCD monitor and uses a different connector - Fortunately, my graphics card supports both. So, not quite isolated yet. I'll try getting the setup panel for the monitor up, thanks.

Comment: I tried hitting the menu button; the control panel did not show.

Comment: Sounds like the graphics-card connector - or components that drive it - used by the first monitor.  Is it possible to try the monitor on another system, or a known-good graphics with your system?  But I'd say the graphics card, being newer, is more suspect.

Comment: It's the monitor or the monitor cable, then; hooking it up to a different computer got the exact same white screen.

Comment: Tested a different monitor cable; same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem. If your not scared of taking things apart open it and make sure all the plugs correctly in place and make sure the moniters power supply is not touching anything it shouldn't be. worked for me :)

Comment: Hmm...Forgot to mark an answer, sorry. This is probably it, but I haven't tried it.